# Customizing JSXgraph fullscreen mode?

Tags: fullscreen, jsxgraph

Fullscreen mode in JSXgraph always adds big gray margins around the board, giving the impression I don't take full advantage of a big screen. Can one configure fullscreen mode, so as to minimize the use of these margins?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question / suggestion! Up to version 1.4.6 it is not possible to configure the size of the JSXGraph board in the fullscreen window.
since this property is hard-coded with the value of 0.85.
I just added the new board attribute `scale` to the source code, available in the fullscreen attribute object:

```
const board2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
    axis:true, 
    boundingbox:[-5,5,5,-5],
    showFullscreen: true,
    fullscreen: {
        scale: 0.99
    }
});
var pol = board.create('polygon', [[0, 1], [3,4], [-1,-4]]);
```

The default value of the attribute will be 0.85. This feature will be available in the upcoming 1.4.7 version.